# CSS - what should I do to solve this?

Tags: css

I use the chosen library and my dropdown appear like this, how can I solve this.
Thanks.[image: dropdown]

Like you can see on the picture the list of values appear under another element instead of being at the first plan, so the list of values is invisible.
What should I change in the CSS to workaround that.

Here is the CSS :

```
/*!
Chosen, a Select Box Enhancer for jQuery and Prototype
by Patrick Filler for Harvest, http://getharvest.com

Version 1.2.0
Full source at https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen
Copyright (c) 2011-2014 Harvest http://getharvest.com

MIT License, https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/blob/master/LICENSE.md
This file is generated by `grunt build`, do not edit it by hand.
*/

/* @group Base */
.chosen-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 13px;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.chosen-container * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.chosen-container .chosen-drop {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: -9999px;
  z-index: 1010;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-top: 0;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.chosen-container.chosen-with-drop .chosen-drop {
  left: 0;
}
.chosen-container a {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* @end */
/* @group Single Chosen */
.chosen-container-single .chosen-single {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 0 0 8px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(20%, #ffffff), color-stop(50%, #f6f6f6), color-stop(52%, #eeeeee), color-stop(100%, #f4f4f4));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 20%, #f6f6f6 50%, #eeeeee 52%, #f4f4f4 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 20%, #f6f6f6 50%, #eeeeee 52%, #f4f4f4 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 20%, #f6f6f6 50%, #eeeeee 52%, #f4f4f4 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 20%, #f6f6f6 50%, #eeeeee 52%, #f4f4f4 100%);
  background-clip: padding-box;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px white inset, 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  color: #444;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: 24px;
}
.chosen-container-single .chosen-default {
  color: #999;
}
.chosen-container-single .chosen-single span {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right: 26px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.chosen-container-single .chosen-single-with-deselect span {
  margin-right: 38px;
}
.chosen-container-single .chosen-single abbr {
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
  right: 26px;
  display: block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: url('chosen-sprite.png') -42px 1px no-repeat;
  font-size: 1px;
}
.chosen-container-single .chosen-single abbr:hover {
  background-position: -42px -10px;
}
.chosen-container-single.chosen-disabled .chosen-single abbr:hover {
  background-position: -42px -10px;
}
.chosen-container-single .chosen-single div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 100%;
}
.chosen-container-single .chosen-single div b {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url('chosen-sprite.png') no-repeat 0px 2px;
}
.chosen-container-single .chosen-search {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1010;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3px 4px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.chosen-container-single .chosen-search input[type="text"] {
  margin: 1px 0;
  padding: 4px 20px 4px 5px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  outline: 0;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  background: white url('chosen-sprite.png') no-repeat 100% -20px;
  background: url('chosen-sprite.png') no-repeat 100% -20px;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: normal;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.chosen-container-single .chosen-drop {
  margin-top: -1px;
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
.chosen-container-single.chosen-container-single-nosearch .chosen-search {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}

/* @end */
/* @group Results */
.chosen-container .chosen-results {
  color: #444;
  position: relative;
  /*overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;*/
  margin: 0 4px 4px 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 4px;
  max-height: 240px;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
.chosen-container .chosen-results li {
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 6px;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 15px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}
.chosen-container .chosen-results li.active-result {
  display: list-item;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.chosen-container .chosen-results li.disabled-result {
  display: list-item;
  color: #ccc;
  cursor: default;
}
.chosen-container .chosen-results li.highlighted {
  background-color: #3875d7;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(20%, #3875d7), color-stop(90%, #2a62bc));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#3875d7 20%, #2a62bc 90%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#3875d7 20%, #2a62bc 90%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#3875d7 20%, #2a62bc 90%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#3875d7 20%, #2a62bc 90%);
  color: #fff;
}
.chosen-container .chosen-results li.no-results {
  color: #777;
  display: list-item;
  background: #f4f4f4;
}
.chosen-container .chosen-results li.group-result {
  display: list-item;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: default;
}
.chosen-container .chosen-results li.group-option {
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.chosen-container .chosen-results li em {
  font-style: normal;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

/* @end */
/* @group Multi Chosen */
.chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 5px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 1%;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(1%, #eeeeee), color-stop(15%, #ffffff));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eeeeee 1%, #ffffff 15%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#eeeeee 1%, #ffffff 15%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#eeeeee 1%, #ffffff 15%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#eeeeee 1%, #ffffff 15%);
  cursor: text;
}
.chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}
.chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices li.search-field {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices li.search-field input[type="text"] {
  margin: 1px 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 25px;
  outline: 0;
  border: 0 !important;
  background: transparent !important;
  box-shadow: none;
  color: #999;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: normal;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices li.search-choice {
  position: relative;
  margin: 3px 5px 3px 0;
  padding: 3px 20px 3px 5px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(20%, #f4f4f4), color-stop(50%, #f0f0f0), color-stop(52%, #e8e8e8), color-stop(100%, #eeeeee));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f4f4f4 20%, #f0f0f0 50%, #e8e8e8 52%, #eeeeee 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#f4f4f4 20%, #f0f0f0 50%, #e8e8e8 52%, #eeeeee 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#f4f4f4 20%, #f0f0f0 50%, #e8e8e8 52%, #eeeeee 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#f4f4f4 20%, #f0f0f0 50%, #e8e8e8 52%, #eeeeee 100%);
  background-size: 100% 19px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px white inset, 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  color: #333;
  line-height: 13px;
  cursor: default;
}
.chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices li.search-choice span {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
.chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices li.search-choice .search-choice-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  right: 3px;
  display: block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: url('chosen-sprite.png') -42px 1px no-repeat;
  font-size: 1px;
}
.chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices li.search-choice .search-choice-close:hover {
  background-position: -42px -10px;
}
.chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices li.search-choice-disabled {
  padding-right: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #e4e4e4;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(20%, #f4f4f4), color-stop(50%, #f0f0f0), color-stop(52%, #e8e8e8), color-stop(100%, #eeeeee));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f4f4f4 20%, #f0f0f0 50%, #e8e8e8 52%, #eeeeee 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f4f4f4 20%, #f0f0f0 50%, #e8e8e8 52%, #eeeeee 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f4f4f4 20%, #f0f0f0 50%, #e8e8e8 52%, #eeeeee 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #f4f4f4 20%, #f0f0f0 50%, #e8e8e8 52%, #eeeeee 100%);
  color: #666;
}
.chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices li.search-choice-focus {
  background: #d4d4d4;
}
.chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices li.search-choice-focus .search-choice-close {
  background-position: -42px -10px;
}
.chosen-container-multi .chosen-results {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.chosen-container-multi .chosen-drop .result-selected {
  display: list-item;
  color: #ccc;
  cursor: default;
}

/* @end */
/* @group Active  */
.chosen-container-active .chosen-single {
  border: 1px solid #5897fb;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.chosen-container-active.chosen-with-drop .chosen-single {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(20%, #eeeeee), color-stop(80%, #ffffff));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eeeeee 20%, #ffffff 80%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#eeeeee 20%, #ffffff 80%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#eeeeee 20%, #ffffff 80%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#eeeeee 20%, #ffffff 80%);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff inset;
}
.chosen-container-active.chosen-with-drop .chosen-single div {
  border-left: none;
  background: transparent;
}
.chosen-container-active.chosen-with-drop .chosen-single div b {
  background-position: -18px 2px;
}
.chosen-container-active .chosen-choices {
  border: 1px solid #5897fb;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.chosen-container-active .chosen-choices li.search-field input[type="text"] {
  color: #222 !important;
}

/* @end */
/* @group Disabled Support */
.chosen-disabled {
  opacity: 0.5 !important;
  cursor: default;
}
.chosen-disabled .chosen-single {
  cursor: default;
}
.chosen-disabled .chosen-choices .search-choice .search-choice-close {
  cursor: default;
}

/* @end */
/* @group Right to Left */
.chosen-rtl {
  text-align: right;
}
.chosen-rtl .chosen-single {
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 0 8px 0 0;
}
.chosen-rtl .chosen-single span {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 26px;
  direction: rtl;
}
.chosen-rtl .chosen-single-with-deselect span {
  margin-left: 38px;
}
.chosen-rtl .chosen-single div {
  right: auto;
  left: 3px;
}
.chosen-rtl .chosen-single abbr {
  right: auto;
  left: 26px;
}
.chosen-rtl .chosen-choices li {
  float: right;
}
.chosen-rtl .chosen-choices li.search-field input[type="text"] {
  direction: rtl;
}
.chosen-rtl .chosen-choices li.search-choice {
  margin: 3px 5px 3px 0;
  padding: 3px 5px 3px 19px;
}
.chosen-rtl .chosen-choices li.search-choice .search-choice-close {
  right: auto;
  left: 4px;
}
.chosen-rtl.chosen-container-single-nosearch .chosen-search,
.chosen-rtl .chosen-drop {
  left: 9999px;
}
.chosen-rtl.chosen-container-single .chosen-results {
  margin: 0 0 4px 4px;
  padding: 0 4px 0 0;
}
.chosen-rtl .chosen-results li.group-option {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.chosen-rtl.chosen-container-active.chosen-with-drop .chosen-single div {
  border-right: none;
}
.chosen-rtl .chosen-search input[type="text"] {
  padding: 4px 5px 4px 20px;
  background: white url('chosen-sprite.png') no-repeat -30px -20px;
  background: url('chosen-sprite.png') no-repeat -30px -20px;
  direction: rtl;
}
.chosen-rtl.chosen-container-single .chosen-single div b {
  background-position: 6px 2px;
}
.chosen-rtl.chosen-container-single.chosen-with-drop .chosen-single div b {
  background-position: -12px 2px;
}

/* @end */
/* @group Retina compatibility */
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min-resolution: 144dpi) {
  .chosen-rtl .chosen-search input[type="text"],
  .chosen-container-single .chosen-single abbr,
  .chosen-container-single .chosen-single div b,
  .chosen-container-single .chosen-search input[type="text"],
  .chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices .search-choice .search-choice-close,
  .chosen-container .chosen-results-scroll-down span,
  .chosen-container .chosen-results-scroll-up span {
    background-image: url('chosen-sprite@2x.png') !important;
    background-size: 52px 37px !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  }
}
/* @end */
```

Comment: Hi,

as you can see on the picture, the dropdown list is not visible when I click to show the list, it appears under. Sorry if it wasn't clear.

Comment: @user3515709 it's good that you have provided CSS, but from the above we just can't see what element has what CSS code. Do you got a working example? Or maybe you could add the HTML/PHP part of it. Also as I can see from the CSS comments you have downloaded the script from here: [http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) Maybe you should read it again, [there are clear instructions](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) how to use it.

Comment: Hi balintpekker, thanks for your answer, I don't think this is a problem with code or the chosen dropdown itself, it is just how it displays in my theme.
As my knowledge in CSS is close to 0, I was wondering if someone could suggest some CSS properties to look at which can be the cause of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elements showing on top or below each other can be managed in css with z-index property.  You may apply -1 for the element that comes on the top.

Read more: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: Hi, I can see in the CSS that a z-index is defined for the chosen-drop and chosen-search classes, the values seem pretty high, but no z-index is defined for the chosen-result which contains the items of the list, what could be the reason ?

Comment: I cannot say reasons, but could you add the same value (1010) to the search part off css for example by firefox dev tool on browser and you would immediately see how it helps or not?

Comment: Dev tools enable you alter css for testing how site works with different settings without touching actual source code. Just play with css settings to find correct combo, which you then can add to actual css file if you have access. For more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console

Answer (score 0):

Place dropdown inside a div with class 'chosen-upward'

```
<div class="chosen-upward">
  your dropdown with class 'chosen-select'
</div>
```

Add to style

```
.chosen-upward.chosen-drop{top:inherit!important; bottom:33px!important;border-bottom-right-radius:0px!important;border-bottom-left-radius:0px!important;border-top-right-radius:4px;border-top-left-radius:4px;box-shadow:none!important;}
```

This will make the dropdown appear above the select control.